# C# Textbox Keypress Control Help

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I have a standard textbox that I want to perform an action on a keypress. I have this code currently:

```
private void idTextEdit_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter/Return)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            SearchButtonClick(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

The problem is, I have tried both Enter and Return up there which is the reason for that. It is only firing that check for normal keys that are not like shift, control, etc. How can I design this so that it will pick up and use the enter/return key in the same way?

Comment: Are you somehow dividing `Keys.Enter` by `Return`?

Comment: @jp2code: The guys below got this one, thanks for checking though. I wasn't very clear about what that meant, I meant to have that there to signify I've tried both, confusing I know and not the best approach but I thought the basic point would get across.

Comment: Yeah, they'd posted their answers before I got all my text in, and were saying just about the same thing. ...so, I contributed by adding the comment, just in case it wasn't something you'd though of. Ya never know! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the `KeyDown` event instead:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

If it for some reason *has* to be `KeyPress`, you can use `(char)13` or `'\r'` for your check, though I doubt that would work well on a non-Windows OS.

```
if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
```

You cannot just cast `Keys.Return` to a `char`, because it's a bitflag enum and doesn't just hold the corresponding ASCII code.

Comment: Ah, lots of things I didn't know before, still learning every day. I switched to KeyDown and it did just what I need. Of note though, the KeyPress event didn't fire at all for a non-character key, so it wouldn't even hit the check if I had to use that in conjunction with (char)13 or '\r'. Still have a ways to go with the learning process but it's moving, thanks for the help and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the KeyDown event instead.